# Customising the output of related products VM2

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

In VM2, I can use the template override default_relatedproducts.php

with the following code:

```
<?php echo $field->display ?>
```

That outputs the HTML

```
<a title="x" href="x">
   <img alt="" src="x.jpg"> 
   Product Name 
</a>
```

Where can I change the output of `$field->display`, as it doesnt appear to be in the templating system?

Has anyone any information on modifying the related products output..

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this forum, so I'm not sure this answer will be what you're looking for.  But, because I see you have had no answers since posting your question in May, I'll give it a shot.

There is a non-commercial extension to Joomla called "K2" which supposedly provides a large number of GUI enhancements and customization capabilities.

In addition, the makers of K2 have also created a COMMERCIAL component called K2mart which, I understand, somehow "bridges" Virtuemart and K2, adding enhanced editing and customization capability to Virtuemart functions.

I have yet to use K2 or K2mart, but from their descriptions, they may be what you're looking for - if you haven't already solved your problem.